# Inserting not committed to database

Tags: c#, ms-access, dataset, oledb

I'm having some trouble getting my DataSet to work.

I have a MDB-Database in the background and created a DataSet out of it. Now I created a new method that lets me create a new user in the table.

But when I call it, nothing happens. No exceptions, no errors and I even get "1" returned as number of affected rows. But when I look in the database, no user was added.

I have the feeling that I miss to somehow tell the DataSet that I want to operate the Database itself rather than just the internal DataSet... How can I achieve this?

```
// DataSet1 uses the connection to the Database.mdb
// Created by the Designer

// The Users table has 3 columns, id, name and password

DataSet1 set = new DataSet1();
UsersTableAdapter adap = new UsersTableAdapter();
DataSet1.UsersRow row = set.Users.AddUsersRow("asd", "asd");
int count = adap.Insert("das", "das");
MessageBox.Show(row.RowState.ToString() + ": " + count.ToString());
count = adap.Update(set.Users);
set.AcceptChanges();
MessageBox.Show(row.RowState.ToString() + ": " + count.ToString());

// The Messagebox shows: "Added: 1"
// The second one: "Unchanged: 1"

MessageBox.Show(set.Users.Rows.Count.ToString());

// Returns "2"...
```

Comment: Can you post some sample code of the DataSet insert method and you calling it?

Comment: Well there isn't really much to see, I created the method in the designer of the Data.xsd as a Query for the Adapter and call it upon an event. The event is fired, I checked that, and the values are not empty nor null ...

Comment: If memory serves, you need to call `Update` on the `DataSet` or the associated adapter.

Comment: Did that, nothing happened...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not knowing too much about your code, try reading this how to from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233812(v=VS.80).aspx

**Update:** with data sets, what would normally happen (assuming the data set has been populated) is rows would be added, edited, or deleted in code.  These rows would have a corresponding `RowState` signifying them as added, edited, deleted, or unmodified.  During the `.Update` the associated table adapter, complete with associated insert/update/delete commands, will iterate the rows and execute the command on a given row depending on the row's state.  When the rows have been iterated, `.AcceptChanges` is called, reverting the row state's to default.

If you call `AcceptChanges` before updating, then nothing will happen.  The `RowState` of each row will be lost so the `.Update` will not have the required information it needs to perform the update to the database.  If you have custom code for wrapping it all in a transaction, then you need to make sure you commit the transaction.

In your example, you seem to imply you are using the table adapter and not the data set itself.  I would advise against this - the table adapters usually place methods on the tables in a data set that you should use.

**Update 2:** the code looks OK to me, though you don't need to call `Insert` on the adapter, or `AcceptChanges` after the update (the latter is done automatically).  This leads me to believe there is a bug in your insert command SQL - try extracting the SQL used by the command and run it manually against the database.

**Update 3:** the following code works fine for me:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        db1DataSet set = new db1DataSet();
        set.Users.AddUsersRow("asd", "asd");

        foreach (DataRow row in set.Users.Rows)
        {
            object foo = row.RowState; // Confirm row state in debugger.
        }

        UsersTableAdapter adap = new UsersTableAdapter();
        adap.Update(set.Users);

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: I did the exact same thing and it still doesn't save any changes. I can use select methods perfectly, but can't change anything...

Comment: Does your DataSet have it's insert command set?  You can see the commands in the designer.

Comment: Yes, it has inserts, updates, deletes, everything. Even if I change their execution modes to direct (what I understand as directly on the database), nothin is saved...

Comment: Are you using any transactions? Do you get any exceptions? Do you call .AcceptChanges before trying to update the DataSet?

Comment: No. It just doesn't save it. I now tried accessing the table via the DataSet using `data.users.AdduserRow()` but that won't work either... Aren't there any good tutorials on that stuff?

Comment: @apoY2k when you said you tried `data.users.AdduserRow()`, did you subsequently call `data.Update()`?

Comment: @ApoY2k can you confirm that the row state of the new rows inside the table have the value `RowState.Added`?

Comment: I added some new code above - It seems to add the rows and the state also is correct...

Comment: I've amended my answer.  I'll need to see the SQL in the insert command, because your sample code looks OK.

Comment: `INSERT INTO \`Users\` (\`name\`, \`password\`) VALUES (?, ?)` Thats the SQL of the "Insert"-Query of the Adapter. If I run that do the database, the values are added without a hassle...

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm out of ideas without a sample application.  Try looking into these links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx(VS.80).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171933(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: Well, I uploaded a small TestApp that displays the error... I would be very very thankful if you could somehow manage to take a look at it... http://vault.apoy2k.de/TestApp.zip

Comment: @ApoY2k I'll take a look when I get home.

Comment: Ok, now this is really emberassing, but I found the error - it was my stupidity. I checked the file in my project explorer not the one that is copied to the Debug-Directory upon compiling. There everything was inserted just the right way. Still, thanks for your help...

Comment: I had just tested this on my machine and it worked for me, I'll post the code I used anyway. The only odd thing for me was the Access driver wasn't working under AnyCPU on a x64 machine, so I set the build to x86.  Don't worry, picnic errors still happen to me sometimes too :-)